# jOOQ join with ANY

Tags: postgresql, jooq

I'm using jOOQ for a Postgresql DB.

I need to run a query like:

```
SELECT tablea.* FROM tablea
  JOIN tableb ON tableb.id = ANY(tablea.array_of_ints)
```

However I don't find any example of using any in a join with jOOQ. 
I tried

```
dsl.select().from(TABLEA).join(TABLEB).on(TABLEB.ID, 
  DSL.any(TABLEA.ARRAY_OF_INTS)).fetch().into(TableA);
```

But is wrong.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is

```
dsl.select().from(TABLEA).join(TABLEB)
.on(TABLEB.ID.equal(DSL.any(TABLEA.ARRAY_OF_INTS)))
.fetch().into(TableA);
```